# how to provide a function for a c++ class that can call a member function by its name

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class f
{
   public:
        run(std::string method,std::string params)
        {
            ...//call foo1 or foo2 with params by "method"
        }

        foo1(std::string a);
        foo2(std::string a);

}
```

I'm trying to make a `map<std::string,std::function<void(std::string)>>` to implement it,but there is a error reported since the non-static member function needs a pointer to an instance.I'm not going to use function pointer like typdef f xxx,I preper to make a map between funcname and function.

Comment: "... but there is an error ..." - you're neither showing the exact error or the code you're using that has the error. How are we to help you fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is possible. You just need the correct prototype in `std::function`'s definition.

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(f*, std::string)>> func_map;
```

The above will of course require that any member function you place here will return `void` and accept a `std::string` by value. No other prototypes will be admissible.

You can store the member pointers like this:

```
func_map["foo1"] = &f::foo1;
```

And then proceed to call them in `run` like so:

```
func_map[func_name](this, arg);
```

---

Ideally, `func_map` should be `static`. So you'd initialize it like so:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(f*, std::string)>> f::func_map {
  {"foo1", &f::foo1},
  {"foo2", &f::foo2},
};
```

---

It's also worth-noting that you don't need to use `std::function` if all you want to store is pointers to members. Those can be stored directly. However, the flip side is that your approach allows for extendabilty!

Any free function which accepts `f` by pointer and a `std::string` by-value can be stored in the map as well.

Comment: If the map only points to `f`'s methods, regular pointers to member functions may be used as an alternative to `std::function`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore if member functions have different signatures. A more general solution would be better for future readers.

Comment: @skypjack - You are welcome to propose it in another answer.

Comment: Interesting. Almost every answer I give to a high profile question today is subject to a downvote. No comment or anything. I'm starting to wonder if someone has it in for me.

Comment: Looks like a revenge vote of one of the other answerers, thinking you were downvoting their answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  - If it is the case I think they are projecting their own behavior onto me.

Comment: nice one! it could be wrapped into macro to automatize it. The `#` can be really helpful here :)

Comment: @W.F. - The table initialization? Yeah it could. Will be quite D.R.Y. I won't suggest it myself however, for fear of the preprocessor inquisition.

Comment: @StoryTeller No need for another answer actually. It was only a comment to improve the answer. One can do that with generic lambdas in C++14 or with an equivalent functor in C++11. That's all. Regarding the downvote: I didn't give you it, but I agree with you that a comment is always welcome.

Comment: @skypjack - I wasn't accusing you. And I'm sorry if it came out that way. I don't think adding a lambda to the mix will go along with my direction here (I'm not sure how free functions can be made acceptable in this case), which is the type erasure added by `std::function`. Which is why I suggested you should post another answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Don't worry, it didn't come out that way. ;-)

Comment: @StoryTeller error C2664: “void std::_Func_class<_Ret,CacomServ *,std::wstring>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,CacomServ *,std::wstring> *)”: cannot convert argument 1 from “_Myimpl *” to “std::_Func_base<_Ret,CacomServ *,std::wstring> *” when I initialize the map like {"foo1", &f::foo1}, I change it to {"foo1", std::mem_fn(&f::foo1)} then it works.Really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using this method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

class f{
   public:
        std::map<std::string,std::function<void(f&,std::string)>> func_map{
            {"foo1",[](auto& obj,std::string params){obj.foo1(params);} }, 
               {"foo2",[](auto& obj,std::string params){obj.foo2(params);} }
            }; // make static or accept inputs from outside the class

        void run(std::string method,std::string params){
            func_map.at(method)(*this,params); // treat exceptions as you want
        }   

        void foo1(std::string a){std::cout << "foo1: " << a;}
        void foo2(std::string a){std::cout << "foo2: " << a;}

};

int main(){
    f fff;
    fff.run("foo1","some_params");
    fff.run("foo2","some_params");
}
```

[Online Example](http://cpp.sh/7d2y)

Answer (score -3):

The only way in C++ is to switch on the string

```
  if(method.compare"PrintButton")
     classobj.PrintButton(atoi(params.c_str());
```

Strings are runtime objects, identifiers are compile time objects.

You can go the template route however to achieve much the same thing.